# Concurrent fx on multiple elements that have the same parent container in ExtJS

Tags: animation, extjs, concurrency, grid, rows

I have an ExtJS GridPanel with associated RowSelectionModel and GridView.  When a user selects some rows and clicks "go", I would like all of the selected rows to flash a few times.

Currently, I'm doing something like:

```
selModel.each(function (record) {

  var doEffect = function (effect, row, color, count, classToToggle) {

     var effectCallback = function (count, max) {
        if (count < max) {
            return (function () { row[effect](color); });
        }
        else {
           return (function () { row.addClass(classToToggle); });
        }
      };

      row.removeClass(classToToggle);
      for (var i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
         row[effect](color, { callback: effectCallback(i, count) });
       }
  };


  // highlight selected rows
  var row = Ext.get(grid.getView().getRow(grid.store.indexOf(record)));

  // essentially calling row.highlight() 3 times 
  doEffect('highlight', row, 'f8f7d6', 3, 'x-grid3-row-selected');  
}
```

The problem is that as the number of selected rows increases, the visual effect no longer happens simultaneously.  I know you can specify concurrent in the effect config, causing all the effects queued up for that element to happen simultaneously, but because all the rows are distinct elements, that doesn't quite work.

It would be awesome if I could somehow specify concurrent on the parent container such that the animation didn't happen until the last selected row was ready to go.

Anyone run into this kind of thing before?

Answer (score 0):

You're setting up callbacks (timers) for each row in turn, and so they may fire at different times.
Try setting up one timer and making the change to all the selected rows at once in there.

That is, remove the selModel.each() loop from outside, and make doEffect and effectCallback take a collection of rows (or query selModel themselves) to change on each call.

It'll run quicker (ie consume less cycles) too as you'll only have the one timer running at once.

Comment: i ended up trying to make a CompositeElement consisting of only the rows i wanted to highlight, which i think is roughly what you're suggesting, and while it was faster, it didn't end up being fast enough. the solution i ended up going with was faking it with css classes and letting the browser do the (optimized) heavy lifting. basically i created a css class on the entire container. then i styled the combination of the parent 'highlight' class and a preexisting row class ('x-grid3-row-selected' from above) to have the same style as a real highlight effect. i wish comments let me format code